# Using variables as an attribute for a module?

Tags: python

Let's say I've got two variables: "choice" = ii7 and "scale" = C.

This library has a function to figure out notes in any particular musical chord by running this:

> chords.ii7(scale)

When scale = C, it'll list the notes of the ii7 chord in the scale of C.

If I had to use the variable "choice" in place of including ii7 in the code itself, how could I go about it? It would definitely be a lot easier to search if I knew what to search for, but I'm a total beginner. This is just to top off the rest of this particular program, and learn something new. Apologies if I worded the title wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
getattr(chords, choice)(scale)
```

This is assuming `choice = 'ii7'`.

`getattr` basically takes two parameters - the first being an object, the second being a string. It searches for an attribute that has the same name as the string, and returns it. In this case `getattr(chords, choice)` returns `chords.ii7`, which you then have to call.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. Really appreciate the help! Definitely going to look more into why that works the way it does, thanks again.